# How can I call the metaclass's __call__?

Tags: python, class, call, metaclass

Given the following example on an instance of a `X` class:

```
class X():

    def __call__(self, incoming_list):
        print incoming_list

X()([x for x in range(10)])
```

How can I obtain the same output by using the `__call__` magic method from the class itself instead of the instance? Example:

```
X([x for x in range(10)])
```

Calling directly, as if passing to `__init__`. But, before it calls `__call__` that calls `__new__` that passes the arguments to `__init__`. How can I access that "metaclass `__call__`" ? Is it possible?

Just to make it easier to understand, this gives me the same output from up there:

```
class X:

    def __call__(self, incoming_list):
        print incoming_list

X().__call__([x for x in range(10)])
```

I want something like this:

```
class X:

    def X.__call__(incoming_list): # Syntax Error
        print incoming_list

X.__call__([x for x in range(10)])
```

Comment: where's your metaclass?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve here. ``def foo(xs): print(xs); foo([x for x in range(10]);`` Really what are you doing with all this magical stuff?

Comment: I know that with a simple function I can achieve exactly the same, but I want to overwrite the class`s default __ call __, not the instance __ call __.

Comment: ... did you try to actually use a metaclass and not just randomly mention it in the question?

Comment: "If you don't know what metaclasses are, the probability that you will not need them is 99%."

Comment: A class does not have a ``__call__`` that you can override. A classes constructor is called ``__new__``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you think too complicated.

Probably you want something like

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, incoming_list):
        self.data = incoming_list # to keep them for later, if needed
        print incoming_list

X([x for x in range(10)])
```

Everything without a meta class, just on definition of the class.

If you need a meta class, you can do it like

```
class MC(type):
    def __call__(self, *a, **k):
    super(MC, self).__call
        print a, k
        r = super(MC, self).__call__(*a, **k)
        print "R", r
        return r

class X(object):
    __metaclass__ = MC
    def __init__(self, x): print "Init", x
```

Using it with

```
>>> X(1)
(1,) {}
Init 1
R <__main__.X object at 0x00000000022907B8>
<__main__.X object at 0x00000000022907B8>
```

shows that the meta-`__call__` is called, which, in turn, calls `__init__`.

But I am sure that you don't need that and that you just want `__init__`.

Comment: Thank you! I know I don`t need it, I was just curious and that was exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Perhaps `__new__` rather than `__init__` in OP's case.